# Return geoprocessing messages to Python IDE

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.7, geoprocessing-framework, logging, ide

I'm using a Python IDE (PyScripter) to run geoprocessing tools in an ArcPy script.

If I were running the GP tools in ArcMap, I'd see various messages in the temporary window that pops up:

[image]

<sup>[Image source](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/foreground-and-background-processing.htm)</sup>

---

Is there a way to return the messages from that dialog to the Python IDE? (similarly to how  `print` statements from the script show up in the Python output window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `getMessages` method of a [tool result](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.8/analyze/arcpy-classes/result.htm):

```
result = arcpy.SomeTool_toolbox(parameters, etc...)
print(result.getMessages())
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe it can be done by adding `print(arcpy.GetMessages())` to the script.

> [GetMessages](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-functions/getmessages.htm) ({severity})
>
> Specifies the severity level of messages to return.
>
> 0 — Messages returned.
>
> 1 — Warning messages returned.
>
> 2 — Error messages returned.
>
> Not specifying a severity level will return all types of
> messages. (The default value is 0)